# what happens when a http request is sent into network

Tags: internet, network-core

If a http request is sent in internet where the request will go and what will happen to the request after finding the IP address.
For example what are all the work done by egress and ingress ,DCHP.
Is there any place where i can learning every step about a web request.

Comment: This question is off topic here.

Comment: Is http request falls outdite network ? then how internet is working trough network or anything else.And i have asked how the request functions in finding dns and how it going through routers. You have answered many questions regarding routers and still this question is off-topic. DCHP is coming under networking concept it seems.

Comment: Yes, HTTP is off topic here. Yes, it uses a network, but not every protocol which uses a network is on topic here. DNS, HTTP and other application protocols are off topic here. This Stack Exchange is meant for questions about networks (layer 1 to 3 of the OSI model). DHCP may be on topic here, but other than that you mentioned that word it doesn't make much sense in this question. You can read more about what's on topic here: [help/on-topic].

Comment: I have raised a question about what happens in DHCP and routing ,once the request is sent out it is then the work of all the 3 layer which u have specified to get me the web page.

Comment: That's basically asking 'how the internet works',which is also off topic here since it's considered common knowledge for people posting and answering here.